# Referenced table not found in standalone Python script

Tags: qgis, python, osgeo4w, qgis-python-console, standalone

I'm trying to run a Python script from OSGeo4W Shell. Im doing this by typing "python-qgis C:\path\test.py"

Everything seems to go fine until the script launches the processing module. After that console gives me a lot of invalid escape sequence warnings.

Then when the script hits the SQL- algorithm it fails to find the referenced table. It still manages to load it.

```
ERROR: Referenced table file in query not found
```

Here is my script:

```
import sys

from qgis.core import (
QgsApplication, 
QgsProcessingFeedback, 
QgsVectorLayer,
QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem,
QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSource,
QgsProcessingFeedback
)

QGIS = 'C:\\Program Files\\QGIS 3.6\\apps\\qgis'


# Prefix
QgsApplication.setPrefixPath(('QGIS'),True)
qgs = QgsApplication([], False)
qgs.initQgis()

# Processing path
sys.path.append('C:\\Program Files\\QGIS 3.6\\apps\\qgis\\python\\')
sys.path.append('C:\\Program Files\\QGIS 3.6\\apps\\qgis\\python\\plugins')

path = 'O:\\Desktop\\Qgis\\File\\file.shp'

IN = QgsVectorLayer(path,'file','ogr')

if IN.isValid():
    print ('Success!')
else:
    print ('Failed!')

OUT = 'O:\\Desktop\\Area\\Leik\\A_Area.shp'

from qgis.analysis import QgsNativeAlgorithms
import processing
from processing.core.Processing import Processing
Processing.initialize()
QgsApplication.processingRegistry().addProvider(QgsNativeAlgorithms())

AO = {
            'INPUT_DATASOURCES': IN,
            'INPUT_GEOMETRY_CRS': QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem('EPSG:3883'),
            'INPUT_GEOMETRY_FIELD': '',
            'INPUT_GEOMETRY_TYPE': None,
            'INPUT_QUERY': 'SELECT \"file\".* \nFROM \"file\"\nWHERE \"file\".\"type\" like \"a%\"',
            'INPUT_UID_FIELD': '',
            'OUTPUT': OUT,
        }

feedback = QgsProcessingFeedback()

result = processing.run('qgis:executesql', AO,feedback=feedback)

print(result)

sys.exit()
```

Answer (score 2):

Those warnings about invalid escape sequences  are in `\lib\site-packages\requests\status_codes.py` and `\lib\site-packages\_plotly_utils\basevalidators.py` scripts and have nothing to do with your script. Upgrade QGIS to the latest stable (3.10) or LTR (3.4) release.

When running your code I didn't find invalid escape sequence warnings. The only strange path is that one ending with `'...\\python\\'`.
Also, you can declare raw strings (`r'...'`) and don't escape the special characters.

All I found was an error in the `AO` dictionary:
In the query, the table must be named `input1` (altought the name of the input layer is `file`).

This code run without errors here (I have changed the path to my files and proposed other way to declare the query):

```
import sys

from qgis.core import (
QgsApplication, 
QgsProcessingFeedback, 
QgsVectorLayer,
QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem,
QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSource,
QgsProcessingFeedback
)

QGIS = r'C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.6\apps\qgis'


# Prefix
QgsApplication.setPrefixPath(('QGIS'),True)
qgs = QgsApplication([], False)
qgs.initQgis()

# Processing path
sys.path.append(r'C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.6\apps\qgis\python')
sys.path.append(r'C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.6\apps\qgis\python\plugins')

path = r'C:\GA\GIS\test\file.shp'

IN = QgsVectorLayer(path,'file','ogr')

if IN.isValid():
    print ('Success!')
else:
    print ('Failed!')

OUT = r'C:\GA\GIS\test\A_Area.shp'

from qgis.analysis import QgsNativeAlgorithms
import processing
from processing.core.Processing import Processing
Processing.initialize()
QgsApplication.processingRegistry().addProvider(QgsNativeAlgorithms())


# Declare a query ready to be modified or include {variables}
import inspect
query = inspect.cleandoc(f'''
    SELECT "input1".*
    FROM "input1"
    WHERE "input1"."type" LIKE "a%";'''
)
print(query)


AO = {
            'INPUT_DATASOURCES': IN,
            'INPUT_GEOMETRY_CRS': QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem('EPSG:3883'),
            'INPUT_GEOMETRY_FIELD': '',
            'INPUT_GEOMETRY_TYPE': None,
            'INPUT_QUERY': query,
            'INPUT_UID_FIELD': '',
            'OUTPUT': OUT,
        }

feedback = QgsProcessingFeedback()

result = processing.run('qgis:executesql', AO,feedback=feedback)

print(result)

sys.exit()
```

Comment: I still get the errors and the escape warnings. Do you run the script with osgeow shell? Did you suggest that IN should be named "input1",

Comment: Yes, I run it with OSGeo4W Shell. I think that just PYTHONPATH variable may be different. No, the layer can have any name, but I need to refer to it as _input1_ in the algorithm.

Comment: Before running the script, try loading the python3 environment with `py3_env` command.

Comment: You mean. Osgeow shell -> py_env -> python-qgis C:path\test.py.  Not working and I still get those errors.. what could be causing those?

Comment: Those are warnings, not errors. I am finding an installation that have them. Are warnings about invalid scape sequences in `\lib\site-packages\requests\status_codes.py` and `\lib\site-packages\_plotly_utils\basevalidators.py` scripts. I am searching if is safe to download those files fixed, but has nothing to do with your script. I mean running just `py3_env` command from the Shell, it loads the path for Python3. Then, run your script with `python-qgis test.py`. But that will not solve the `status_codes.py` and `basevalidators.py` deprecation warnings.

Comment: Yes those scripts are giving the DeprecationWarnings : ivalid escape sequence \d etc.

Comment: Still the script fails to run. It says Cannot find layer input1_4f11b.....  There were errors executing this algorithm

Comment: I think that you will need to upgrade QGIS version.